# Compile hello.cpp. flags - C++ FAISS GPU

Tags: c++, linux, gpu, intel-mkl, faiss

I would like to use FAISS C++ GPU externally in another repo. Therefore, I created a hello.cpp and tried to compile it without going into the faiss directory. Inside the faiss directory, compilation seems fine to me.

- hello.cpp (C++ Faiss GPU):

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <faiss/gpu/GpuIndexIVFPQ.h>
#include <faiss/gpu/StandardGpuResources.h>
#include <faiss/gpu/GpuCloner.h>
#include <faiss/utils/random.h> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <faiss/gpu/utils/DeviceUtils.h>
#include <faiss/gpu/utils/Timer.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <faiss/gpu/GpuAutoTune.h>
#include <faiss/index_io.h>
using namespace std;

double elapsed() {
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec * 1e-6;
}
int main() {
    double t0 = elapsed();
    printf("[%.3f s] Hello World! :))\n",
           elapsed() - t0);
    faiss::gpu::StandardGpuResources res; // Without this line, nvcc works.

    return 0;
}
```

**Command:**

`/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc /home/hossamamer/hello.cpp  -lcublas -lfaiss  -o myCublasApp`

**Output:**

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libmkl_intel_lp64.so, needed by /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libmkl_gnu_thread.so, needed by /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libmkl_core.so, needed by /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so: undefined reference to `dgemm_'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so: undefined reference to `dgetri_'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so: undefined reference to `dgetrf_'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so: undefined reference to `ssyrk_'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so: undefined reference to `sgetrf_'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so: undefined reference to `sgelsd_'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so: undefined reference to `sgemm_'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so: undefined reference to `dgesvd_'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so: undefined reference to `dsyev_'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so: undefined reference to `sgeqrf_'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so: undefined reference to `sorgqr_'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so: undefined reference to `sgesvd_'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so: undefined reference to `sgetri_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

*Any help? Can I also do this using the make command? What is the command?*

Comment: faiss evidently expects you to link against intel MKL.  First you'd need to install MKL if you haven't already.  Then you would need to add some mkl libs to your command line.  See [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/blob/main/INSTALL.md) "The basic requirements are: ...
a BLAS implementation (we strongly recommend using Intel MKL for best performance)."

Comment: Thanks. Installing Intel MKL makes it work.

Any idea if I need FAISS C++ GPU externally in another repo and compile using cmake. What are the changes I need to do for cmake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your logs:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libmkl_intel_lp64.so, needed by /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libmkl_gnu_thread.so, needed by /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libmkl_core.so, needed by /usr/local/lib/libfaiss.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

You faiss installed in /usr/local, and it compile with mkl as blas library.
So you need to install mkl for using it.
As you say:

> Inside the faiss directory, compilation seems fine to me.

It seems your mkl library is already in your build source tree, you could try to find them if already in your faiss build directory.

Answer (score 1):

you should install OpenBLAS or MKL first.
[install](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/blob/main/INSTALL.md)